# Count for many-to-many relationship

Tags: join, count, psql, many-to-many

I have the following tables:

```
surveys            properties   owners_properties        owners
---+------------   ----------   ------------+---------   ------
id | property_id   id           property_id | owner_id   id
```

I want to find the count of surveys that have more than one property owners.

Here is a rough stab:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM surveys 
JOIN properties ON surveys.property_id = properties.id 
JOIN owners_properties...
HAVING count(properties.id > 1);
```

Comment: So you are using Postgres? ([psql] is the tag for the command line interface.) What do you get for `SELECT version();`? And by "more than one property owners", do you really mean "more than one *distinct* property owners"?

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  In SQL Server, you have to GROUP BY before you state HAVING.  Personally, I would do something like this

```
    SELECT COUNT(id) Surveys_w_2_LandOwners
    FROM surveys s
        JOIN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(1),property_id
            FROM owners_properties
            GROUP BY property_id
            HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        ) p ON p.property_id=s.property_id
```